# method is not defined js

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

How come this code throws an

> Uncaught ReferenceError:logRiver is not defined.

```
function createRiver (name, continent,lengthInKilometers){
    let obj = {
        name:  name,
        continent: continent,
        lengthInKilometers: lengthInKilometers,
        isLongerThan:function(riverObject) {
             if(this.lengthInKilometers>riverObject.lengthInKilometers)
                return true;
             else
                return false;
            
            },
         logRiver:function(){
            console.log(`The ${this.name} river is ${this.lengthInKilometers} kilometers 
            long.`)
        }
        }
        return obj;

}
```

is it to do with the symbol ${}?

Comment: This code has no obvious errors, please show where you use the result of this function

Comment: `let test1=createRiver("Amazon","somecontinent",500)
    let test2=createRiver("Denoba","somecontinent",400)
    console.log(test1.isLongerThan(test2))//true
    console.log(logRiver(test2))//logRiver is not defined`

Comment: @YakirAvraham Same as for `.isLongerThan`, you need to call `test1.logRiver()`.

Comment: …and no, this has nothing to do with template literal syntax.

Answer (score -1):

The symbol `${}` is the templating format for adding in variables in between the special templating (template literal) strings `CODE` to replace this form of string writing so that isn't the issue here.

The error in the code is that you have not defined any function or element for the logRiver portion and are then trying to run a function inside a non existing term `logRiver:function(){`

All you have to do is define logRiver as something or to reformat the function into something like the proper arrow format and then call the function below it. for example

```
// with logRiver being returned as a constant you can reference later and this being an inputted object with the needed information
const logRiver = function (example){
  console.log(`The ${example.name} river is ${example.lengthInKilometers} kilometers long.`);
};

// then you can call it to check

console.log(logRiver);
```

EDIT: My mistake - it seems like the `logRiver:` is another format to do the same thing I defined that I wasn't aware of. The issue would then be in the test data of the code.

Comment: You cannot use `this` as a parameter name.

Comment: Yeah my bad - I just used it as an example parameter name for an inputter array of info. OP should follow good naming standards